# After upgrading react I get this errror on the console

Tags: reactjs

-This is the error I get after runnig 'npm start'

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

[screenhoot from the browser notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC23Y.png)

it says that there a problem with the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And this is the Header component

```
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Header.css';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import DeelnemerOverlay from '../../assets/images/deelnemer- 
 overlay.jpg';
import CoachOverlay from '../../assets/images/coachOverlay.jpg';

const header = (props) => (
<div className={classes.Image}>

<div className={classes.Deelnemer}>

<h2>Informatie voor Deelnemers</h2>
  <br />
  <img alt='deelnemer' src={DeelnemerOverlay}></img>
  <br />
  <br />
<p>
  <Button bsStyle="primary">Meer over deelnemers</Button>
</p>
</div>
<div className={classes.Coach}>
<h2>Informatie voor Coachen</h2>
 <br />
 <img alt='coach' src={CoachOverlay}></img>
 <br />
 <br />

 <p><Button bsStyle="primary">Meer over coachen</Button></p>
 <br />
 </div>
 </div>
 );

 export default header;
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: please, show the code for `header`

Comment: I guess you didn't export the component in the error

Comment: @TomasEglinskas which component yo mean?

Comment: @streletss I added now to the question..

Comment: that's not what I've meant.. I'm asking about `header` component. (@TomasEglinskas mentioned it as well)

Comment: @streletss Thank for you fast answer. I added the Header component..(see question)

Comment: It is solved. In the Header component my bootstrap was not working properly. I solved trough downgrading my bootstrap from 4 to 3

Answer (score 1):

It is solved. In the Header component my bootstrap was not working properly. I solved trough downgrading my bootstrap from 4 to 3